# How do i create a formula to calculate from using 2 cells, every other column?

Tags: excel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB7Do.png

The very top row is the KEY for the rest of the responses.

So looking at this image, I am trying to do =IF(F3=$F$2,1,0) located at G3. This works for this specific column to convert correct answers to '1' and incorrect to '0'and i can drag this formula down all the way and it works. However, how do i "drag" this formula across my row for more questions so that the next one would be,=IF(H3=$H$2,1,0), and this formula would be located at I3. I have like 200 questions so obviously i wouldnt want to go to each column and change numbers manually, i need G3,I3,K3...etc to all have the respective formula.

Comment: If you put `=IF(F3=F$2,1,0)` in G3 and drag it down it will work for that column but if you copy the formula from G3 and paste it to I3 it should automatically change the formula to reference H and then you can drag it down that column too.  the difference between my formula and yours is that since $ makes that bit fixed saying F$2 allows the column to change but not the row.

Comment: So when i copy paste is there any way to have the F$2$ to change to H$2$ automatically? currently it would not unless i got rid of the $. when i do what you have my column does not change

Comment: The $ signs go before the thing they modify so what I am saying is that `F$2` allows the column to change and leaves the 2 fixed which is exactly what you need.  So use `=IF(F3=F$2,1,0)`

Comment: never mind i see, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The dollar signs in a cell reference determines which parts of the cell reference change when the formula is copied to another cell:

- `$A$1` the dollar signs before each piece means neither the column nor row will be updated when the formula is copied.
- `$A1` the dollar sign before the column means that only the column is fixed - the row will be updated when the formula is copied.
- `A$1` the dollar sign before the row means that only the row is fixed - the column will be updated when the formula is copied.
- `A1` no dollar signs means that both the column and row will be updated when the formula is copied.

So if `=IF(F3=$F$2,1,0)` is copied from G3 to I4 the formula will be updated to say `=IF(H4=$F$2,1,0)` because:

- the `F3` part has no dollar signs so neither piece is fixed and both the column and row change when it is copied.
- the `$F$2` part has dollar signs on both the column and row so neither piece will change when it is copied.

You want only the column to be able to change in the `$F$2` reference so you need to use `F$2` instead.  So use `=IF(F3=F$2,1,0)` as your formula.

Answer (score 0):

You remove the $ signs completely and copy paste (normally) the formulas to the I and K columns.

```
=IF(F3=F2,1,0)
```